# Exclude column from export in jQuery Datatables

Tags: datatables

I'm using jQuery datatable 1.10.11 and it's export button functionality as described [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/simple.html):

I want to skip last column from being export into excel file as this column has edit/delete buttons in it. My columns are generated dynamically so I can't use following method:

```
    $('#reservation').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Export Search Results',
            className: 'btn btn-default',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I know this question is asked multiple time but non of them worked for me, might be version issue.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try using CSS selector that excludes last column for `columns` option.

```js
$('#reservation').DataTable({
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [
      {
         extend: 'excel',
         text: 'Export Search Results',
         className: 'btn btn-default',
         exportOptions: {
            columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
         }
      }
   ]
});
```

Answer (score 48):

You can add a class:

```html
<th class='notexport'>yourColumn</th>
```

then exclude by class:

```js
$('#reservation').DataTable({
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [
   {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export Search Results',
        className: 'btn btn-default',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(.notexport)'
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: Honestly this is the answer most of you will be looking for. Its more dynamic allowing you to just add a class to whichever columns you don't want to export which is great for many use cases. As well this can give you better control when you have multiple export options.

Comment: @CodeSpent yes, i agree with that. Perfect for my case

Answer (score 11):

I just thought I'd add this in because the accepted answer only works to exclude if you are not already including something else (such as visible columns).

In order to include only visible columns except for the last column, so that you can use this in conjunction with the Column Visibility Button, use

```
$('#reservation').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export Search Results',
        className: 'btn btn-default',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible:not(:last-child)'
        }
    }]
});
```

And if you want to explicitly add your own class:

```
    $('#reservation').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export Search Results',
        className: 'btn btn-default',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible:not(.notexport)'
        }
    }]
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! for the code: `columns: ':visible:not(.notexport)'`

Comment: A man that thinks well! that was much needed! thanks

Answer (score 1):

for Excel, csv, and pdf

```
dom: 'lBfrtip',
buttons: [
    {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel',
        titleAttr: 'Export to Excel',
        title: 'Insurance Companies',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(:last-child)',
        }
    },
    {
        extend: 'csvHtml5',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i> CSV',
        titleAttr: 'CSV',
        title: 'Insurance Companies',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(:last-child)',
        }
    },
    {
        extend: 'pdfHtml5',
        text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> PDF',
        titleAttr: 'PDF',
        title: 'Insurance Companies',
        exportOptions: {
            columns: ':not(:last-child)',
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: thanks, you posted full code, so it is faster for us.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, I copied it from PDF button.
E.g **columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]**.
Check this documentation: **https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/columns.html**

```
buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
              columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
            }
        },
        {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            exportOptions: {
              columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Javascript Part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'print',
            exportOptions: {
                // columns: ':visible' or
                columns: 'th:not(:last-child)'
            }
        },
        'colvis'
    ],
    columnDefs: [ {
        targets: -1,
        visible: false
    } ]
} );
```

} );

And the js files to be included:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js
```

Hope this was helpful for you.
Thanks.